How make ADS1115 send ALERT pulse?
I am working on a PIC32 with an ADS1115 https://docs.rs-online.com/85d7/A700000007080221.pdf#page=28&zoom=100,0,96.
I put the ALERT pin of the ADS on an external interrupt of the PIC32. I nerver go in the interrupt and with a analogique analyser i don't see any pulse.
ADS has his adress pin on GND and i use that code to init him (I use I2C) :
    I2C2_CallbackRegister(MyI2CCallback, NULL);
    I2CDataVector[0] = 0b00000001; // ADC Config register address 
    I2CDataVector[1] = 0xD4; // * , AIN1 to GND, 6V, Continuous 0b11010000
    I2CDataVector[2] = 0b10000000 ; // 128 SPS, ALR at all conversion  0b10000000

    if(!I2C2_Write( ADS1115_ADDRESS, &I2CDataVector[0], 3 ))
    {
        Lcd_Set_Cursor(2,1);
        Lcd_Write_String("I2Wr2");
    } 

Does anyone have an idea to have that pulse to use the external interrupt of the PIC ?

In order to use the ALERT/RDY as a conversion ready pin, the user needs to set the COMP_QUE register to '00' to assert after a single conversion, and needs to set the MSB of the high threshold register to '1' and the MSB of the low threshold register to '0"
